# How can I create a bar chart that has multiple yAxes scales?

Tags: bar-chart, chart.js

I have the following code:

```
data = {
    labels: ["CategoryA", "CategoryB"],
    datasets: [
        {
           label: "Group A",
           data: [95, 1]
        },
        {
           label: "Group B",
           data: [80, 3]
        }
    ]
};

new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: data, 
        options: option
});
```

My goal is to directly compare the numbers in `Group A` and `Group B` per category. However, the bars for `CategoryA` take up the entire vertical space while `CategoryB` is barely visible.

**How can I make `CategoryA` display on a scale from 0 to 100 and `CategoryB` on a scale from 0 to 5?**

EDIT:
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/risVv.jpg) was the problem I had. Was unable to make a solution with only one graph, ended up just using two separate ones. If anyone knows how to do it in one graph, please let me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no built-in method in ChartJS to achieve this at the moment.

Though, one way I can think of achieving this, is to create two different charts and place them on top of each other, as such ...

```js
// CHART 1
var data = {
   labels: ["Category A", "Category B", "Category C"],
   datasets: [{
      label: "Group A",
      data: [95, 0, 0],
      backgroundColor: 'blue'
   }, {
      label: "Group B",
      data: [60, 0, 0],
      backgroundColor: 'red'
   }]
};
var option = {
   scales: {
      yAxes: [{
         ticks: {
            min: 0,
            max: 100
         }
      }]
   }
}
new Chart(ctx, {
   type: 'bar',
   data: data,
   options: option
});

// CHART 2
var data2 = {
   labels: ["Category A", "Category B", "Category C"],
   datasets: [{
      label: "Group A",
      data: [0, 1, 2],
      backgroundColor: 'blue'
   }, {
      label: "Group B",
      data: [0, 3, 4],
      backgroundColor: 'red'
   }]
};
var option2 = {
   scales: {
      yAxes: [{
       position: 'right',
         ticks: {
            min: 0,
            max: 5
         }
      }]
   }
}
new Chart(ctx2, {
   type: 'bar',
   data: data2,
   options: option2
});
```

```css
#chart-wrapper {
   display: flex;
}
#ctx2 {
   position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<div id="chart-wrapper">
   <canvas id="ctx"></canvas>
   <canvas id="ctx2"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: I think this makes the datasets have different y-axes. I'm looking for the categories to have different y-axes.

Comment: If it's not possible, then the only option would be to create two charts and place them next to each other?